# Symfony2 - Give a default filter in a list of elements of Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have a list of elements of type Vehicle and I show these elements with Sonata Admin. I allow to filter these elements by the "status" field, but I want that, when the list is showed, only the active vehicles are showed, and if somebody wants to see the inactive vehicles, uses the filter and select the inactive status. I would like to know if somebody Knows the way to apply filters by default for a list of elements using Sonata Admin.

Here is my code:

```
public function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('name')
        ->add('status')
    ;
}

protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $mapper)
 {
     $mapper
         ->add('name')
         ->add('status')
     ;
 }
```

Is there any option that can be added to the status field in configureDatagridFilters() to achieve this goal? Other options?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to override `$datagridValues` property as following (for `status > 0` if it's an integer) :

```
   /**
    * Default Datagrid values
    *
    * @var array
    */
   protected $datagridValues = array (
           'status' => array ('type' => 2, 'value' => 0), // type 2 : >
           '_page' => 1, // Display the first page (default = 1)
           '_sort_order' => 'DESC', // Descendant ordering (default = 'ASC')
           '_sort_by' => 'id' // name of the ordered field (default = the model id field, if any)
      // the '_sort_by' key can be of the form 'mySubModel.mySubSubModel.myField'.
   );
```

source: [Configure the default page and ordering in the list view](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-0/doc/reference/advance.html#configure-the-default-page-and-ordering-in-the-list-view)

Comment: Thank you so much PéCé!! I had been looking for information on Internet several hours. I can not vote up for your answer because I have no enough reputation, but I will vote up your answer as soon as possible.

Comment: You're welcome ! I had found that configuration info at https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/reference/advance.rst#configure-the-default-page-and-ordering-in-the-list-view

Comment: You sir, you saved me a headache!

Comment: I don't understand what's the meaning of `type`. Can you explain ?

Comment: This refers to the operator of filter, look at the comment at the end of line ;-) Type with value "2" means "greater than"

Answer (score 11):

You can also use this method

```
    public function getFilterParameters()
    {
        $this->datagridValues = array_merge(
            array(
                'status' => array (
                    'type' => 1,
                    'value' => 0
                ),
                // exemple with date range
                'updatedAt' => array(
                    'type' => 1,
                    'value' => array(
                        'start' => array(
                            'day' => date('j'),
                            'month' => date('m'),
                            'year' => date('Y')
                            ),
                        'end' => array(
                            'day' => date('j'),
                            'month' => date('m'),
                            'year' => date('Y')
                            )
                        ),
                    )
                ),
            $this->datagridValues
            );

        return parent::getFilterParameters();
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Using both above suggested approaches will break the filters "reset" behaviour since we are always forcing the filter to filter by a default value. To me, i think the best approach is to use the getFilterParameters function (since we can add logic in there instead of statically add the value) and check if the user clicked the "Reset button"

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getFilterParameters()
{
    // build the values array
    if ($this->hasRequest()) {
        $reset = $this->request->query->get('filters') === 'reset';

        if (!$reset) {
            $this->datagridValues = array_merge(array(
                'status' => array (
                    'type' => 1,
                    'value' => 0
                ),
            ),
                $this->datagridValues
            );
        }
    }

    return parent::getFilterParameters();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't want to work. The value is in my filter, but the filter is not applied. If I click `Filter` nothing happens, but when I reset the filter and then choose the value, it does work

Comment: I had to remove `'type' => EqualType::TYPE_IS_EQUAL` in my case

Answer (score 3):

Since sonata-admin 4.0, the function `getFilterParameters()` is tagged as final and the $datagridValues doesn't exist anymore.

So you need to override the `configureDefaultFilterValues()` function

```
protected function configureDefaultFilterValues(array &$filterValues): void
{
    $filterValues['foo'] = [
        'type'  => ContainsOperatorType::TYPE_CONTAINS,
        'value' => 'bar',
    ];
}
```

More details: https://symfony.com/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/current/reference/action_list.html#default-filters

Comment: This is the best answer for actual versions

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use createQuery and getPersistentParameters to enforce invisible filter. This approach is best to have fully customizable filters. See my articles here:

http://www.theodo.fr/blog/2016/09/sonata-for-symfony-hide-your-filters/