# Symfony - Set Sonata Admin filter operator to “is equal to” as default option

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I know there is the same topic :

[Symfony - Set Sonata Admin filter operator to "is equal to" as default option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540098/symfony-set-sonata-admin-filter-operator-to-is-equal-to-as-default-option?rq=1)

but no answer.

I want to do the same thing :

In sonata admin I have a working filter in my admin class:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('client.name');
}
```

The filter will default to match "contains" (LIKE operator) like this:

[image]

I would like the filter to use "is equals to" (= operator) as the default option instead of "contains":

[image]

Unfortunately I couldn't find questions or answers related to this in SO, google, and the [Sonata docs 9.4 
filters](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/action_list.html#filters) is currently not documented.

How can I do this?

Comment: [Does this help maybe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213361/symfony2-give-a-default-filter-in-a-list-of-elements-of-sonata-admin)

Answer (score 0):

An answer after a long time. You can override default filter options by overriding the variable `$datagridValues`

```
protected $datagridValues = array(
        'email' => array(
            'type' => 3,
            'value' => ''
        )
    );
```

`'type' => 3` means its `equal to`

Comment: Better to use the class constant use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\Filter\ChoiceType

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to do that with SonataAdmin, i need to use jQuery for example.